# Compiling code lacking configuration script in Readme

Tags: make, github

I am trying to install a handy program which takes xyz files and turns them into `POVRAY` input scripts: [github](https://github.com/GezelterLab/xyz2pov)

I have cloned the repository locally, however the first instruction

```
"run ./configure" does not exist in any directory.
```

Is there any way to analyze the `src code` or `makefiles` in order to compile this one my own machine?

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a configure script *template* in the `ac-tools` subdirectory:

```
$ ls ac-tools/
aclocal.m4  config.guess  config.sub  configure.in  install-sh  Make.conf.in  shtool
```

You can create the configure script from the template using `autoconf`

```
autoconf -o configure ac-tools/configure.in
chmod +x configure
./configure
```

Comment: ... or using the supplied `Makefile`: `make configure`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Doh! didn't even think to check there - yes that's a simpler option.